# What is the strange chirping noise?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've started to notice a strange chirping noise anytime I go to specific place, especially behind a tree. But it doesn't follow around, it stays in the same place. Does anyone know what it is? It sounds kinda like a squirrel or chipmunk...

Comment: It could be an insect such as a cricket.

Comment: No, its not a cricket. I caught a cricket and donated it to Blathers Museum but its a different sound but I do think it could be a different bug. I'll keep an eye out, Thank you.

Comment: If you enter and leave a shop/house, is the noise still there? If not it probably isn't a bug since they would be repopulated into a new random location at that point.

Answer (score 3):

What you are hearing is a [Mole Cricket](http://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-leaf/Mole_Cricket).

They live underground, so you have to dig to get them.